# Как работать с динамическим именем переменной в JavaScript без eval()?

Tags: javascript, amd, eval

Как внутри функции обратиться к динамическому имени переменной без `eval()`?

Упрощённый пример ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/nozud333/)):

```
(function(){
    var Obj = {
        f: function( A, B, C){
            var r = "ABC".split("")[ Math.floor( 3 * Math.random())];

            // как вывести a, bb или ccc без eval()?
            console.log( eval(r));
        }
    };

    Obj.f( 'a', 'bb', 'ccc');
})()
```

Обращаться нужно именно по имени переменной, а не через `arguments[]`.

**Update** Это для модуля контроллера в Backbone/require приложении. Живой пример упрощённо выглядит примерно так:

```
define(
    [
        'app/views/about',
        'app/views/auth',
        'app/views/dashboard',
        'app/views/default',
    ],

    function(
        vAbout,
        vAuth,
        vDashboard,
        vDefault,
    ){
        var Controller = {
            go: function( page) {

                var View = eval('v'+page);

                if( typeof View == 'object') {
                    console.log('rendering view', page);
                } else {
                    console.warn( 'No page view defined for', page);
                }
            }
        };

        return Controller;
    }
)
```

Comment: Задача сам по себе оло-ло, вам нужно вывести именно по названию переменной? Или вам не важно как, просто рандомный аргумент отобразить?

Comment: В модуль контроллера requirejs передаётся несколько Видов backbone. Позже из роутера вызывается метод контроллера, с параметром - именем вида. Метод должен показать запрошенный вид, либо дефолтный.

Comment: А в каком контексте будут находиться переменные? Просто вверх по контексту, или глобальные?

Comment: Всё равно не очень понимаю, что вы делале, может это похоже на http://code.re/663

Comment: @ReinRaus обновил вопрос куском кода

Comment: @RubaXa, да, пожалуй надо сделать так.  Спасибо!

Comment: Ну и просто добавлю, что без eval это сделать невозможно, нельзя получить текущий контекст в JavaScript.

Comment: непонятно зачем это надо, если есть arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У RequireJS есть «[сахар](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar)»:

```
// router.js
define(["ctrl"], function (ctrl) {
  // бла-бла-бла
  ctrl.open("MyPage");
});

// views.js
define(function (require) {
  var views = {
    MyPage: require("view/MyPage"),
    defaults: require("view/Default")
  };

  return {
    get: function (name) {
      return views[name] || views.defaults;
    }
  };
});

// ctrl.js
define(['views'], function (views) {
  return {
    open: function (name) {
      var View = views.get(name);
      // ...
    }
  };
});
```

**UPD**: [[@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus)](/users/481/reinraus), just for fun :]

```
function getArgumentValueByName(args, name) {
    var names = args.callee.toString().match(/\(([^)]+)/)[1].split(/\s*,\s*/);
    var i = names.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (names[i] == name) {
            return args[i];
        }
    }
}

function myFunc(a, b, c) {
    var value = getArgumentValueByName(arguments, "b");
    return value;
}

console.log(myFunc("fail", "wow!", 3));
```

Comment: @RubaXa, на upd. Ну да. Здесь заведомо известно, что требуемые переменные это arguments в цепочке вызывающих функций, я же имел ввиду общий случай, когда например переменная объявлена через var в вызывающей функции.

Comment: В таком случае проще переписать на объект, либо и в правду использовать eval

Comment: @ReinRaus `arguments.callee()` не поддерживается в [`strict` режиме](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode). Отчасти ради соответствия strict'у затеял отказ от eval'а.

Comment: arguments.callee тоже не проблема, можно просто дополнительно передать ссылку на функцию.

Comment: @RubaXa, и поиметь проблем при минификации :) я думаю надо делать, как в angular либо просто сделать функцию, вызываемую примерно так:

    var namedArgs=getNamedArgs(
        ['About','Auth','Dashboard','Default'],
        arguments);

Это вроде бы ненамного сложнее, чем просто получить эти аргументы в объявлении функции.

Comment: @eicto, ну да, но так и так, правильное решение, это работать с объектом, а всё остальное эзотерика.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, можно сделать [такой трюк](http://jsfiddle.net/nozud333/2/):

```
var container = {};
container.A = A;
container.B = B;
container.C = C;
```

и обращаться как `container[r]`. Наверняка у js есть более приятный синтаксис для 
этого.